# Array changes value after exiting loop

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have used while loop to fetch values from a database & assigned them to an array. However, when the loop is exited; the value changes.

```
$i=1;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM opportunities WHERE location = '$location'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) 
{
 $job[$i]= $row1['id'];
 echo $job[$i] . "is the ID of the Job opening with this location <br>";

  $job[$i][1] = 3;
  $i=$i+1;
  echo $job['$i'];


}

echo $job[1]. $job[2];
```

While I am inside the loop job["i"] returns a different value to the second instance. Thank you in advance. Sharing further code on request of the comments

```
$sq4 = "SELECT * FROM opportunities WHERE skill1 = '$skill'";
$result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sq4);
while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)) 
{$id4=$row4['id'];
echo $id4 . "is the ID of the Job opening matching the skill you entered as the most important skill<br>";
 $job[$i]= $row4['id'];
 $job[$i][1] = 3;
  $i=$i+1;}
```

Output: For the first loop, results in the loop(first instance) are 27 & 29. 
Outside the loop, the results are 23 & 23. 23 is the first value of the next loop (if that is correlated in any way)

Comment: What is the expected and current output?

Comment: You don't need the double quotes in the index, you do need a $ before `job` though

Comment: @RST made a mistake copying the code. Corrected it. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @u_mulder There are loops beyond this loop. (I have just copied a part of it. ) If it helps, 23 is the first value of the next loop. Edited the question. Kindly have a look

Comment: And why you do `$job[$i][1] = 3;`?

Comment: I would want to display results in the decreasing order of their relevance. $job[$i][1] measures the relevance of result for match in `location`= '$location'. Likeways, skill1 has a relevance match of 3, again. Some other paraments are rated at 4,2 and 1. At the end, I will sum these values to reflect sum-relevance
P.S. This is done to measure relevance of search query to existing entries in database

Comment: You still have quotes in place where they are not needed.

Comment: @RST... Select statement ?

Comment: @RST Checked and removed for both the select statement. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the following code result in?

```
$sql     = "SELECT * FROM opportunities WHERE location = '$location'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$jobs    = array();
$i      = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $jobs[$i]['id']        = $row['id'];
    $jobs[$i]['relevance'] = 3;

    $i++;
}

var_dump($jobs);
```

Comment: This works but dont understand why mine does not :-O